# Add listener to custom observable component in Nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am trying to have my custom component notify its users when a selection is made but I am having issues receiving the event.

Home component uses the custom component `FavouriteListComponent`:

**home.component.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

    @ViewChild('favouriteList', { read: ElementRef }) fl:ElementRef;
    private favouriteCourses: FavouriteCoursesComponent;

    ...

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.favouriteCourses = <FavouriteCoursesComponent> this.fl.nativeElement;
        this.favouriteCourses.on('selected_course', function(course_id) {
            console.log("on");
            this.tabsComponent.gotoNewGame(course_id);
        });
        console.log("ngAfterViewInit");
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.favouriteCourses.off("selected_course");
    }

}
```

**home.component.html**

```
    <GridLayout row="4">
        <ns-favouritecourses #favouriteList></ns-favouritecourses>
    </GridLayout>
```

**favouritecourses.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ns-favouritecourses',
  ...
})
export class FavouriteCoursesComponent extends Observable implements OnInit {

  ...

  playCourse(courseId: number): void {
    console.log("notifying...");
    this.notifyPropertyChange('selected_course', courseId);
  }

}
```

In the log I can see the event being sent through "notify" but it is never received in my listener although the listener seems to be added fine although it probably is not.

How can I send the event from `FavouriteListComponent` to the `HomeComponent`?

Comment: Since you are using Angular, make use of [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) instead of {N} Observable.

Answer (score 0):

you should just use event emitter, and subscribe to the event where ever needed.

HTML:

```
  <ns-favouritecourses (selected_course)="changed(this)" #favouriteList></ns-favouritecourses>
```

TS:

```
@Output() Change: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  changed(value : any){
    this.Change.emit(value);
  }
```